# Multi host Kafka-zookeeper Hyper-ledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, docker-swarm-mode

I am trying to setup a Multi Org Multi Host network based on Hyperledger fabric block chain. I developed a network structure and trying to run docker containers in swarm mode. I have three aws instance Ubuntu on aws.
Here is link of my public repository  https://github.com/medipal/MultiOrgNetwork

When I am running docker images there are no services replicated.
There is error while deploying the network thats why container are not starting.
How can I build a network like this or What should I have to correct in my code?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I updated the description.Please review. Thanks

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: Error occurring while starting network. docker daemon error : rpc code unknown in Zookeeper service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a great example of a [orderer-kafka network](https://github.com/keenkit/fabric-sample-with-kafka). This is the first-network from fabric-sample with kafka. You need to adjust this to work in swarm mode and apply you changes.